# PHP my admin no Ignore duplicate rows option for importing CSV files

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a CSV file that I successfully imported into a database table.

Over time I will update this CSV file with new data so I was wondering if I import the same file which will contain rows that has already been inserted into the table, is there a way to avoid duplicates being added again?.

When researching I came across an option called "Ignore duplicate rows" however this is not present for me within the import options.

I am using the PHP my admin that is packaged inside XAMPP.

which is •Version information: 4.2.7.1, latest stable version: 4.2.8

Comment: tried that did not work, still puts in duplicates

Comment: do you have a unique index on your table?

Comment: yes each row has a primary key that is on auto increment

Comment: What about if exists, else? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx You could modify the update to just skip the record.

Comment: @user3364963 you need to create a unique index on the columns you want to be unique (maybe all columns except the pk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add unique key to your database column which you think should be unique

here is the code i have done for uploading csv files which will stop inserting found values maybe it will help you.

using On Duplicate Key Update

```
<?php
$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("dbname");


 $csv_file="/path/to/file";
 $savefile="filename.csv";
 $handle = fopen($csv_file, "r");

$i=0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { //2nd param is for memory limit use it if u know what u are doing
    if($i>0){

        $import="INSERT into table_name(col0,col1,col2,col3)values('".addslashes($data[0])."','".addslashes($data[1])."','".addslashes($data[2])."','".addslashes($data[3])."')ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2= '".addslashes($data[1])."'";
        mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
    }
    $i=1;
}   
?>
```

cheers

Comment: Thanks, I used PHP which done it. The way I check for duplicate was a bit different because im dealing with lottery results (there can not be two results with the same date). I just run a query to get the latest date and earliest date store it in variable and then compare the date from CSV to this (in UNIX time stamp format). If date from CSV is greater than latest, then add it. If its less than the earliest then is historical results so add it.